# admin.auth(...).createSessionCookie is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'am trying to manage firebase auth sessions exactly as documentation [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies) says but when i request via Ajax with a post method "/loginSession" node Js return me this :

```
 `error: TypeError: admin.auth(...).createSessionCookie is not a function
    at app.post (C:\Projectos\Eventos\functions\index.js:48:16)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Projectos\Eventos\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Projectos\Eventos\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Projectos\Eventos\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Projectos\Eventos\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Projectos\Eventos\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Projectos\Eventos\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Projectos\Eventos\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at urlencodedParser (C:\Projectos\Eventos\functions\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:82:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Projectos\Eventos\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)`
```

here is how i manage the request

```
app.post('/loginSession',(req,res)=>{
  const idToken = req.body.idToken.toString();
  const expiresIn = 60*60*24*5*1000;
  admin.auth().createSessionCookie(idToken,{expiresIn}).then((sessionCookie)=>{
    const options = {maxAge:expiresIn,httpOnly:true,secure:true};
    res.cookie('session',sessionCookie,options);
    res.end(JSON.stringify({status:'success'}));
  },error=>{
    res.status(401).send('error');
  });
});
```

I'm using express, body-parser and firebase
Firebase Version 3.18.4
Node version 8.9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `createSessionCookie()` method (and other session management methods) were introduced in Firebase Admin SDK version 5.12. See the [changelog for the Firebase Admin SDK for Node](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/releases/tag/v5.12.0). Upgrade to the latest release to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I've just realized that i need version 5.12.0 or higher